# How to get Firestore SnapShotListener to only listen for newly created documents?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

When I add a `SnapshotListener` to a Firebase query like so:

```
EventListener<QuerySnapshot> initialQueryListener = new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    switch (documentChange.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:

                            Message message = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Message.class);

                            mMessages.add(message);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

The code in the ADDED case is being called for every single document being pulled down from Firestore, not just the ones that are being added to the collection. It took me an embarassing amount of time to realize this. I would like to have separate `SnapshotListeners`: one for the inital queried messages, and another that only pulls down new ones. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you not assume that the first call to onEvent contains only present documents, and all future calls are only updates to that set?

Comment: Yes, that is sort of the problem. The code that adds them to the list needs to be different based on whether or not they are present at the first call or added after, in order for the messages to appear in order. The code above works for the initial call, but new messages need to be added at position [0] of mMessages.

Comment: You can certainly keep track of how many times onEvent has been called in your callback object.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that information.

Comment: The first time it's called, do what you said you need to do with the first set of messages.  Each subsequent time it's called, do what you said you need to do for the additional messages.  I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: Aha! That made it click for me. Thank you so much for your response.